# How to create widget element with unlimited values?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a widget for a field as shown below:

[image: widget]

I would like to make the text field ('script_paths') an unlimited value so that the user can add as many as they like. Is there a way to do this? Maybe there is a property I add in my code below:

```
function mango_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

  $field_name = $instance['field_name'];
  $required = $element['#required'];
  $item =& $items[$delta];
  $element += array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
  );

  $element['enabled'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Enabled'),
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#default_value' => isset($item['enabled']) ? $item['enbled'] : '',
  );

  $element['script_paths'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Script Paths'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => isset($item['script_paths']) ? $item['script_paths'] : '',
  );

  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would think that there would be a property as well but I can't think of one for text fields. I know that you can use [field collections](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) though.

**Edit:** I was mistaken Field Collections will not work for custom forms, however [This tutorial](http://rapiddg.com/blog/use-ajax-support-multiple-item-values-custom-drupal-7-forms) worked for me.